# Only basic parameters are honoured in ImageResizer console app

Tags: imageresizer

I am using ImageBuilder.Current.Build(imageStream, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=200&crop=auto&s.grayscale=true")) in a console application, but only width and height attributes are applied, the s.grayscale parameter is ignored. I have installed the SimpleFilters plugin from nuget, and I have added it in the plugin section in app.config. Any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### .NET 4.0 doesn't load .dlls unless there is a static code reference.

Use the code installation method during startup instead of XML:

```
new SimpleFilters().Install(Config.Current).
```

Comment: It was new SimpleFilters() etc for me... good spot, surely this should be mentioned in the docs!